# Navigating through html with BeautifulSoup from a specific point

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using the following piece of code to find an attribute in a piece of HTML code:

```
results = soup.findAll("svg", {"data-icon" : "times"})
```

This works, and it returns me a list with the tag and attributes. However, I would also like to move from that part of the HTML code, to the sibling (if that's the right term) below it, and retrieve the contents of that paragraph. See the example below.

```
<div class="382"><svg aria-hidden="true" data-icon="times".......</svg></div>
<div class="405"><p>Example</p></div>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do this properly. Searching for the div class names does not work, because the class name is **randomised**.

Comment: so in this example, what actually you are trying to extract? is that the `<p>Example</p>` section?

Comment: Yes, I would like to find the <p>Example</p>, specifically the one right below the svg above it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS selector with `+`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div class="382"><svg aria-hidden="true" data-icon="times"> ... </svg></div>
<div class="405"><p>Example</p></div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

div = soup.select_one('div:has(svg[data-icon="times"]) + div')
print(div.text)
```

Prints:

```
Example
```

---

Or without CSS selector:

```py
div = soup.find("svg", attrs={"data-icon": "times"}).find_next("div")
print(div.text)
```

Prints:

```
Example
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! In the case of multiple tags containing the "times" data-icon attribute, whats the best method for that?

Comment: @Adnos You can use `for tag in soup.find_all("svg", attrs={"data-icon": "times"})`. and then `tag.find_next("div")`